# Automate Business Process inside excel file that has a lot of setting tables

Tags: c#, excel, database-design

Automating Manual Salary Calculations that is running inside Excel File

i have an excel File that do salary calculations for international expert that join a project 
the salary scale is depending on a lot of things including (Hardship of duty station, duration of employment , level of personnel etc
in one of the excel file sheets all the settings value listed there 
i.e:

- Personnel Information
- StartDate:
- EndDate:
- Married:
- HasKids:
  .. etc.

> Levels/Grade(Levels from P1 to P5 and each level can have degree from
>   1 to 13)

```
Level          BasicSalary
---------      -----------
P1/I - P1/II       $71,000.00  
P1/II - P1/III     $77,000.00
```

> - Hardship (CountryLevel country in general safe)
> - Hardship (City Level some cities are safe within the country)

```
Country      Category   Amount
-------      --------   ------
Country1        A          $000  
Country2        Z          $400.00


City        Country   Category   Amount
-------   ---------   --------   ------
City1      Country1      A     $000  
City2      Country2      Z     $400.00
```

'A' The safest, 'H' is the most dangerous if countries is safe in general city details needed in the city hardship table.

> - Medical Contribution

```
salary married   w/child Except(CountryName) w/children  W/EUROPE w/child   
------- -------- ------- ------------------- ----------- -------- -------
3,100   444.23    +24       768.34             +24      720.59     +24
3,200   440.56    +24       762.48             +24      714.48     +24
```

my question is there a best practice in saving these settings value, i am using asp core 2.2 code first migration some of the table in the excel file has irregular pattern like the medical contribution where the values is not for country only you can include regions and there are exceptional cases.

i have an initial solution that looks like this

```
 **public class City
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Category { get; set; }

        public virtual Country Country { get; set; }

        public int? CountryId { get; set; }

    }
 public class Country
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }


        public string Category { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; } = new List<City>();
    }

  public class Grade
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }
    }

  public class Level
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }
    }

 public class MedicalContribution
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public decimal MonthlySalaryScale { get; set; }

        public decimal WorldWideContributionAmount { get; set; }

        public decimal WesternUnitContributionAmount { get; set; }

        public decimal ChileAndMexicoContributionAmount { get; set; }

    }**
```

I don't want to continue on this and ended up in the bad practice trap, i am looking for the best practice. thanks in advance

Comment: did you actually tag an excel-related question with 'database-design'? you really should look into replacing excel as your storage!

Comment: i want to replace existing excel file  that calculate the cost int a fully automated web application with automated solution

Comment: good idea! what is your question then?

Comment: my question is what is the best practice to follow in order to save these settings that were mentioned in the question

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing

Comment: Do you mean you want to create an application like this one: https://info.undp.org/gssu/onlinetools/SalCalcInt/SalCalcInt.aspx ? If so, then maybe you can talk to the guys at UNDP and then get back to the SO community in case you get stuck with a particular part of your application ? I agree with @SanchoPanza, as it stands, your post is not really a question this community can help you with.